# NodeJS ~ I changed my function from sync to async and now my code won't work

Tags: node.js, facebook, asynchronous, recursion

I am trying to recursively get all of my Facebook posts, using the Facebook Graph API.

A simple GET request to Facebook's API won't return all of my posts. Rather, it returns a **paginated response**.

```
{"data": [
     {Facebook post},
     {Facebook post},
     {Facebook post}.
     etc
    ],
  "paging": {
          "next":Url (api endpoint) to next page of results
   }
}
```

So, I have to **recursively** make GET requests on paging.next to retrieve all of my posts.

**Doing this with a synchronous** HTTP request was easy. But I am using NodeJS, and I keep hearing that I should keep things async. So, I changed my HTTP GET request method to be **asynchronous**.

To get some control flow on my async HTTP GET request, I am using the **async** npm module; particularly, **async.waterfall**

Here's my **recursion** function with async.waterfall:

```
function getAllPosts(responseObj, masterPosts) {


    masterPosts = typeof masterPosts !== 'undefined' ? masterPosts : {'data':[]};
    var posts = responseObj['data'];
    masterPosts['data'] = masterPosts['data'].concat(posts);
    if (responseObj.hasOwnProperty('paging') && responseObj['paging'].hasOwnProperty('next')) {
    var r;

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            r = httpGet(responseObj['paging']['next']);
            callback(null, r);
        },
        function(arg1, callback){
            getAllPosts(JSON.parse(arg1), masterPosts);
            callback(null, 'done');
        },
    ], function (err, result) {
        //result now == 'done'
    });
    }
    return masterPosts;
}
```

**httpGet** function is asynchronous. I tried this, but it doesn't work :( My result is still only half of my Facebook posts.

the function argument **responseObj** is a JavaScript object ~ just parsed the paginated JSON response

What am I missing here?

Comment: Here you have synchronous part as you need to wait for one request to finish so you can get next URL and do next request. The async part is making a request and waiting for response. For handling async stuff I would recommend using Promises.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example, if possible?